# I can not login to GitHub account in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github

I generated an access token in GitHub with required scopes as following

[image]

[image]

[image]

The added token in GitHub login section an android studio and gives an Invalid AUTH Data  as following

[image]

So, How can I login? and is there a way to login through android studio terminal?

Comment: Have you tried logging in the normal way? i.e email & password?

Comment: For sure, i thought about it's a crash connection between GitHub API and whole IDE, so i updated IDE to the latest version and worked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I solve that by updating Android Studio IDE to the latest version